EU Flight Cancelled x 1 then not allowed on flight as 2nd leg waitlisted
hoping for some advice for those with knowledge of EU rules re: flights. My partner and I are Australian and we have a very different system (TL;DR airlines can do what they want).
We had flights from Amsterdam to Melbourne book through Thai Airlines. It was structured this way:

Amsterdam to Frankfurt (with Luthansa - booked via Thai though)
Frankfurt to Bangkok (with Thai)
Bangkok to Melbourne (with Thai)

Unfortunately leg 1 was the morning of the worldwide IT issues and as expected the flight was cancelled. We were given tickets for a rebooked flight immediately which was structured this was:

Amsterdam to Hong Kong (with KLM)
Hong Kong to Melbourne (with Qantas)

We noted when arriving back at our hotel that the second list said "wait list". We assumed it was due to the massive numbers of rebookings being done due to the IT issues and we would get to the airport early the next day to sort it out (work case scenario we get on leg 1 then get rebooked to Melbourne from Hong Kong - of note the Luthansa app said leg 1 with KLM was confirmed).
We arrived at the airport 4 hours early and went to check in. After 2 hours the flight attendants couldn't book us in - after main stressful calls to Luthansa + Thai Airways nothnig could be done and we missed the flight (by missed I mean coulnd't get on it). In the words of the flight attendant - we had seats, but Thai Airways or Luthansa (they didn't know who) hadn't "confirmed" the flight.
After this I called Luthansa to talk about rebooking a flight. The operator explained the issue was that leg 2 was on a wait list so they didn't release leg 1 for us. At this point it has as a "no show" for leg 1 on his end (hopefully this will correct in the next day or 2) and that he could only rebook on partner airline and at this stage there was no flights in the next 3 days and he couldn't book anything beyond that.
He said essentially our options were book with an airline out of their network (he said on the phone flights were available via Qatar or Singapore Airlines) and chase Luthansa or Thai for the money or wait in Amsterdam and get on a rebooked flight but he couldn't give us a time or day.
We are extremely fortunate to have financial means to book our own flight and as such will be flying with Qatar to Melbourne tomorrow midday for $4000 Euros.
My understanding is step 1 will be for Luthansa to recognise we couldn't board the KLM flight due to leg 2 being on a wait list. Then to negotiate them re: reimbursing the Qatar flight as they couldn't provide
Step 2 will then be using the following rules to get reimbursed (via https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#reimbursement-overbooked-1). My interpretation is Luthansa has not fulfilled their obligation to provide a flight at "The earliest opportunity" as whilst their own network airlines had no flights Qatar and Singapore did.
Does this all sound correct? Just hoping for some advice before I lodge this with Luthansa once the dust settles. Overall I don't really care about the money but it freaks me out to think what someone would do if they were tight on money (living in Amsterdam for another 3 days could be pricey!) and I'm quite annoyed we weren't told iniitally by Luthansa we can't board our KLM flight until the Qantas flight is confirmed - wasted our time and the time of 2x KLM flight attendants + the call centre people from Thai Airlines.

To be honest, looks very risky. I would have requested a reimbursement of an extra 3 nights at hotel + expenses instead of risking 4000 euros. By the way, KLM and Qantas are "out of network" airlines for Lufthansa, so if they could book you on them they definitely could have done the same for Qatar. also Singapore Airline is definitely "In-network" for Lufthansa, they are in the same airline alliance (as is Thai airways). I am afraid you might have got a lazy or untrained agent.

I am a bit concerned about the flight being flagged as "no show", this is definitely not something that will get fixed by Itself. the system now shows you had a flight and you didn't show up (forfeited it). It would be a mess to explain it the more time passes. I would have escalated with the call centre people until they get someone who can correct it right then. as you were already in the airport, did you try going to the Thai or Lufthansa service desk there to get it figured out?

So another update - we booked with Qatar and are checked in - in the security line we received an email from Luthansa saying he had a flight with Emirates booked as a replacement (so the "no show" issue must have been resolved). Only kicker is that from the time receiving the email to check in closing was 50 minutes (assuming we were in a hotel without packed bags it would have been impossible to make this).
We received no information from Luthansa prior to this email and it was completely out of the blue. The last correspondence was verbal saying 'no flights for 3 days min").

The other issue is at the time of trying to check in there were no Luthansa or Thai Air representatives at the airport. Our attempts to escalate were met with Thai Air saying it was up to Luthansa, Luthansa saying it was up to Thai Air and KLM saying they didn't know why they couldn't process it. Our plan is to write a letter of compensation to Luthansa explaining the situation and request our Qatar Fee. I recognise they replaced our flight today (50 minutes notice) but we were told it would be 3 days minimum so were not expecting this Emirate flight.
